# Async fundamentals for threading a loop

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I am hoping this is a pretty simple example of code that I am trying to understand.

I would like to keep starting the process over while waiting for a long running process to complete. The goal is to run all batches at the same time. For example:

```
while(moreToProcess())
{
   var batch = CreateBatch();
   await ssisMethod(batch); //takes 30 seconds and would like to start next batch
   CreateAndSendReports(batch); //Must wait for ssisMethod to complete
}
```

I am concerned I don't understand the flow of my code.

1. Will it kick off another batch while waiting?
2. Will it wait to complete before creating reports?

as requested:

The important part i think:

```
      public static async Task ssisMehtod(varBatch)
      {                      
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cstr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Integer).Value = batchID;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.VarWChar, 9).Value = DUNS;
                    conn.Open();
                    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: --> it will wait to complete before creating reports. However it would also depend on what you wrote on `ssisMethod` For example fire and forget some task.. Can you post the code of that method too.

Comment: thank you. I am trying to convert sync to async

Comment: You can read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/ which will give the clarify about async/await.

Comment: @user1672994. I will read that article, but i have also posted the relavent part of the method in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer you question:

1. No, It will not kick off another batch while waiting. What it does is just free up the main thread, so your main thread/UI thread won't hang there.
2. Yes, it will wait until the `ssisMethod` returns before `CreateAndSendReports`

To achieve your goal, you can just wrap your method `CreateAndSendReports` to async. And create another wrapper method e.g. `ProcessBatch`.

```
public static async Task ProcessBatch(Batch batch)
{
  await ssisMethod(batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
  await CreateAndSendReports(batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

while(moreToProcess())
{
   var batch = CreateBatch();
   ProcessBatch(batch).ConfigureAwait(false); //Program will not wait here, it will proceed to create another batch.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save all tasks and run them together after the WhenAll code continues

```
       var tasks = new List<Task>();

        while (condition is true)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var batch = CreateBatch();
                await ssisMethod(batch); 
                CreateAndSendReports(batch); 
            }));
        }

        Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```